# Invers functions on manifolds

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, manifolds, inverse

I know that For a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, any function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the condition

- $(f \circ g) (x)=x$
- $(g \circ f) (x)=x$

$g$ would be the inverse function of $f$. I was wondering weather that work for manifolds or not.

I have this function

$$F:\mathbb{R}P^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$$

$$F([x,y,z])=[-x,z,y]$$

I notice that

$(F\circ F) ([x,y,z])=F([-x,z,y])=[x,y,z]$

Then I conclude that $F$ is its own inverse. But then I had some questions:

1. Can a function be its own inverse (on $\mathbb{R}$ or any other manifolds)?
2. Is the definition of inverse function on $\mathbb{R}$ holds for manifolds?
3. I feel like that $(F\circ F) ([x,y,z])=F([-x,z,y])=[x,y,z]$ does not guarantee that $F$ is its own inverse because of the equivalence classes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can be its own inverse, yes. On the reals, consider $f(x) = -x$.

On $\Bbb R^2$, reflection about the line $x = y$ is another such map, defined by
$$g(x, y) = (y, x).$$

The same is true for manifolds --- there can be functions that are their own inverses ---  and you've constructed an example, one that's mostly made up as a combination of the functions $f$ and $g$ I mentioned above.

There's no problem with equivalence classes at all.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! I really understand it now. Thanks

Comment: But this particular function $F$ on $\Bbb RP^2$ is a well-defined function on $\Bbb R^3$ (without equivalence classes) and as such it *is* its own inverse as a linear map $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$. This would not be the case if we wrote $f(x,y,z)=(-2x,2z,2y)$, even though $f$ induces the same map $F$ on projective space.

Comment: Good point, Ted. What I meant was that for this particular function, there was nothing about equ. classes to worry about because for any repreesentative $u$ of some class, you get $f(f(u)) = u$, rather than $f(f(u)) = v$ where you'd then have to prove that $v$ and $u$ lie in the same class. Bad phrasing, but it seems to have worked. :)